# grails run-app > can't see terminal input

Tags: grails, console, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

On Ubuntu 12.04, when I run `grails run-app`, after stopping the app, the terminal cursor doesn't move when typing, and no text appears. I can still type commands, but I have to either do it blindly or use `reset` to reset the terminal. Has anyone else seen this behavior? Ive tested in grails 2.0.1, 2.0.4, 2.1.2 and 2.2.1. The same behavior happens for all. Any suggestions?

Comment: `grails --plain-output run-app` should disable the use of ANSI colour codes, which might help.  Which terminal program are you using?

Comment: GNOME 3.4.1.1. I'll give that a try an report back.

Comment: @Ian That seemed to work. If you want to post an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grails --plain-output run-app` should disable the use of ANSI colour codes, which might help, depending on which terminal program you're using.